# PaymentIntent requires authentication when SetupIntent was successfully - Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, 3d-secure

We have an integration with Stripe but now we working with 3D secure. In our system, when the user registers we have to give permissions to the card to later charge. So, by the documentation that we analyzed we created and confirmed a SetupIntent but when creating the carge (PaymentIntent) of stripe return is  "Your card was declined. This transaction requires authentication."

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any idea? Thanks all

Comment: Make sure you're using the proper [Regulatory test card](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#regulatory-cards) and not just the plain 3DS test cards.

Comment: Hi. Yes, we use the regulatory test cards

Comment: Has that changed anything? In the screenshot above you were using the card ending in 3220 which is not a regulatory card (it's a plain 3DS card). The card you need to use is the one ending in 3155.

Answer (score 2):

You can use stripe regulatory test card 4000002500003155 which will not request additional authentication for future off session payments for testing. But some cards requires authentication on all transactions, regardless of how the card is set up.

[Check this for further reference](https://stripe.com/docs/testing)